# Transpose limit characters 50000 problem in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to use this formula:

`=sort(unique(transpose(split(arrayformula(concatenate(if(len(C3:Y195)>0,C3:Y195&";",""))),";"))))`

But the characters limit is not enough. How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome. Would you please share your spreadsheet. It's quite difficult to tell how to solve such a problem without know what the data looks like, as well as the proposed outcome.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pR0OyCiIFecLkIwSIwx6llLECpnzHt97zPsybjm8i6g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Welcome. I've looked at your spreadsheet - that's quite a formula but its purpose isn't obvious. Please explain the problem that you are trying to solve with this spreadsheet and the formula (as well as the other formulae) on the "ID Unico" sheet. Re-read the help section on [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your question to provide more information.

Comment: FWIW, the formula in question was doomed from the start. Possibly you've adapted it from another Q&A, but it is fatally flawed. The heart of the formula is `len('EMPLOYEE DEC'!C3:Z192)`, but all the values on "EMPLOYEE DEC" are text (test it with `istext()`), and `len` expects numbers. Also, the formula appears to appears to duplicate (though transpose) the data on "EMPLOYEE DEC"; that's a recipe for a very big and sluggish spreadsheet. Hopefully we can help you get a more efficient solution when you describe the problem you're trying to solve.